# Function not successfully reading sensor registers

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, i2c, accelerometer, wire-library

I'm trying to write a library for an accelerometer/magnetometer sensor.  The sensor is a LSM303D chip (https://www.pololu.com/file/0J703/LSM303D.pdf).

I've written a function, `readRegister()` (below) that's supposed to get the data from the sensor.  However, I put in many different registers into the function into the function, but it always returns the same number.  That number changes every time I unplug my Arduino from my computer.

```
byte fp::readRegister(byte register_address, int numBytes) {
  Wire.requestFrom(register_address, numBytes);
  byte c;
  Serial.println(Wire.read());
  while (Wire.available()) {
    c = Wire.read();
  }
  Serial.print("0x");
  Serial.print(register_address, HEX);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(c);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.println(millis());
  return c;
}
```

Here's an example of the problem output:

```
0x8 190 2 
0x9 190 3
0xA 190 11
```

And here is something more like what I'd expect:

```
0x8 193 [time]
0x9 189 [time]
0xA 195 [time]
```

Here is the Git repo with the rest of the code: https://github.com/fpdotmonkey/fp_accel

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Could you show the rest of the code? Is there a `Write.endTransmission()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```C++
  Wire.requestFrom(register_address, numBytes);
  byte c;
  Serial.println(Wire.read());
  while (Wire.available()) {
    c = Wire.read();
  }
```

This has a number of problems. For one thing your (I presume) debugging print consumes the data from Wire.read, so when you go to get it into c, you have already printed it. In other words, you are reading byte #1 and printing it, but using byte #2. This seems an odd thing to do.

Next, what is this doing?

```C++
  while (Wire.available()) {
    c = Wire.read();
  }
```

You are reading an indefinite number of bytes, and retaining the last one. Why?

Possible rework:

```C++
byte fp::readRegister(byte register_address, int numBytes) {
  Wire.requestFrom(register_address, numBytes);
  byte c = Wire.read()
  Serial.println(c);
  Serial.print("0x");
  Serial.print(register_address, HEX);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(c);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.println(millis());
  return c;
}
```

---

> Here is the Git repo with the rest of the code: https://github.com/fpdotmonkey/fp_accel

From your linked code:

```C++
  byte xlm = readRegister(fp::OUT_X_L_M, 1);
  byte xhm = readRegister(fp::OUT_X_H_M, 1);
  byte ylm = readRegister(fp::OUT_Y_L_M, 1);
  byte yhm = readRegister(fp::OUT_Y_H_M, 1);
  byte zlm = readRegister(fp::OUT_Z_L_M, 1);
  byte zhm = readRegister(fp::OUT_Z_H_M, 1);
```

You have the wrong end of the stick here.

```C++
  Wire.requestFrom(register_address, numBytes);
```

You request from the **I2C address** - that is the device address. The register is something else.

Judging by the datasheet you first have to send the register address, and then request the data. Something along the lines of:

```C++
byte fp::readRegister(byte register_address, int numBytes) {
  Wire.beginTransmission (DEVICE_ADDRESS);
  Wire.write (register_address);
  Wire.endTransmission (false);  // repeated start
  Wire.requestFrom(DEVICE_ADDRESS, 1);
  byte c = Wire.read()
  Serial.println(c);
  Serial.print("0x");
  Serial.print(register_address, HEX);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(c);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.println(millis());
  return c;
}
```

Similarly for writing to a register:

```C++
void fp::writeRegister(byte register_address, byte val) {
  Wire.beginTransmission(DEVICE_ADDRESS);
  Wire.write (register_address);
  Wire.write(val);
  Wire.endTransmission();
}
```

This is untested because I don't have the device here, but I know that what you had won't work. To check the actual device address run the [I2C scanner](http://www.gammon.com.au/i2c) I mentioned before.

Comment: I'm still experiencing the same problem.  Every register address I plug in returns the same value.

Comment: It would help to see the whole sketch and not just a function being called in an unknown way. It would also help to see your improved code. Are you sure you are communicating with the device? Can you do a `WHO_AM_I` and get back the right response? It's hard to debug a [snippet](http://snippets-r-us.com/).

Comment: Also confirm you have the right device address, and it is connected correctly. There is code to do that on [my page about I2C](http://www.gammon.com.au/i2c) - scroll down to the "I2C scanner".

Comment: My codebase, as well as the improved function, are in the Github link that is now in the original question.  When I try to read from WHO_AM_I, I get the same response as from every other register.

Comment: Well, see my amended reply. That is not how you access registers.

Comment: I've updated the code on Github to have what you've written as well as the address from your program, but I still get the same results.  I thought since the number it returns for every register is 255 that it may be the size of the type byte that is the problem, but I changed the function to return an int, and it did the exact same thing.  I know that the chip is good because I can get other people's libraries to run on it.

Comment: Please post the output of running the I2C scanner that I requested.

Comment: The first few lines of output, as well as the output of your I2C scanner, are [here](https://github.com/fpdotmonkey/fp_accel/blob/master/output.txt).  The chip I'm concerned with now is the 0x1D.  The 0x6B is the gyro sensor that's on the same board.

Comment: I see I made an error (or retained your error). The line which read `Wire.requestFrom(register_address, 1);` should have been `Wire.requestFrom(DEVICE_ADDRESS, 1);`. I fixed up my reply.